# Internal Compiler Error: Unknow Magic Member

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle

I am trying to compile a contract using truffle and I am not able to find what this error is related to.

EggFactory.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract EggFactory{

    uint dnaDigits = 16;
    uint dnaModulus = 10 ** dnaDigits; //10000000000000000

    event NewEgg(uint eggId, uint dna);

    struct Egg{
        uint dna;
        uint createdAt;
        bool hatched;
    }

    Egg[] public eggs;

    mapping (uint => address) public eggToOwner;
    mapping (address => uint) ownerEggCount;

    function createEgg(uint _dna) public{
        uint id = eggs.push(Egg(_dna,now,false)) - 1;
        eggToOwner[id] = msg.sender;
        ownerEggCount[msg.sender]++;
        emit NewEgg(id, _dna);
    }

    function generateRandomDna() private view returns (uint){
        // Get the now time, concatenate it with the last blockhash and hash it
        uint rand = uint256(keccak256(now, block.blockhash));
        return rand % dnaModulus;
    }

    function createRandomEgg() public{
        require(ownerEggCount[msg.sender] == 0);
        uint randDna = generateRandomDna();
        createEgg(randDna);
    }
}
```

EggHatching.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

import "./EggFactory.sol";

contract EggHatching is EggFactory{

    uint hatchTime = 1 days;

    function hatchEgg(uint eggId) public {
        require(msg.sender == eggToOwner[eggId]);
        require(hasHatched(eggId) == true);
        eggs[eggId].hatched = true;
    }

    function hasHatched(uint eggId) internal view returns (bool){
        return ((now - eggs[eggId].createdAt) >= hatchTime);
    }

    function getEggType(uint eggId) internal view returns (uint){

    }
}
```

I am aware that the logic of the contract in itself might be flawed in some aspects.

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you're seeing? And when do you see it? (What command did you run?)

Comment: `$ truffle compile`


I obtain the following:


`Compiling ./contracts/EggFactory.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/EggHatching.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...

InternalCompilerError: Unknown magic member.
Compilation failed. See above.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`block.blockhash` takes a block number as parameter. Replace

```
uint rand = uint256(keccak256(now, block.blockhash));
```

with

```
uint rand = uint256(keccak256(now, block.blockhash(block.number)));
```

and it should compile.

Also, note that a miner can influence the value of `now`, and thus the value of `rand`.

Comment: Can the downvoter please give their reason?

Comment: Thank you. Is this "unknown magic member" something you came across by yourself in the past, or did find any documentation explaining it?

Also, regarding the RNG, I'm completely aware of it. I'm currently in the process of experimentation with solidity and smart contracts and just wanted to verify some concepts I learned.

Comment: I found a compiler error using Remix on that line, and checked [this page](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) to find the usage of blockhash.